# How is class inheritance hierarchy being mapped by Grails mongodb plugin?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

We are using MongoDB plugin in Grails.

So I found this code, a domain object called `Address`:

```
public class Address extends EmbededDomain{
    static mapWith = "mongo"

    Region region;
    Zone zone;

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'identity'
        region reference:true
        zone reference:true
    }
}
```

`EmbededDomain` is a class in `src/groovy`

```
class EmbeddedDomain {
    public EmbeddedDomain() {
        this.dateCreated = new Date()
        this.lastUpdated = new Date()
    }
}
```

Then I have `Organization` domain with relationship **Organization has Address:**

```
class Organization {
    static mapWith = "mongo"

    Address address

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'identity'
    }
}
```

What does region `reference:true` mean?

After saving an`Organization` when I enter the command `show Collections` in my MongoDB console I am not seeing collection with name `Address`? rather I am seeing collection with name `EmbededDomain` which contains all the Address, why is this happening `EmbededDomain` is just a Groovy class.

Comment: I think `reference:true` needs to be its own question?

Comment: Asked it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185330/gorm-what-is-referencetrue-in-grails-domain-class-mapping-block