# GORM: What is reference:true in Grails domain class mapping block?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

```
public class Address {
    static mapWith = "mongo"

    Region region;
    Zone zone;

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'identity'
        region reference:true
        zone reference:true
    }
}
```

I'm interested in knowing what `reference:true` does.

In my experience, leaving it off gives exactly the same result except  there's no `DBRef` in the actual mongo document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `reference` controlls how documents are linked.

When `true`, the related documents are referenced by [db-refs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/), if `false`, GORM inserts simple `id`, aka `Manual references` in mongo

Comment: Thanks injecteer! Is there any benefits to having documents referenced by db-refs with GORM? The manual says "Unless you have a compelling reason to use DBRefs, use manual references instead."

Comment: from the very same docu: `By including these names, DBRefs allow documents located in multiple collections to be more easily linked with documents from a single collection`. so, if you need to link docs from a  single collection, manual refs are just fine

Comment: But that information can be found at the domain class definition. So GORM knows which collection to look for by seeing the class of the field, right?

Comment: In general, both options are working, but I think that db-ref might be better optimized

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel Also have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412341/mongodb-is-dbref-necessary) for why using references in mongodb is not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

This means that those properties will be stored on your Address record by reference.  The id for Region and the id for Zone will exist on the record when you query the database instead of storing the entire object's mapping and any objects that its mapping may contain. Returning the Address object would look something like this:

```
{
  "id": "2413",
  "region": DBRef("region", "1234"),
  "zone": DBRef("zone", "4321")
}
```

For non-embedded associations by default GORM for MongoDB will map links between documents using MongoDB database references also known as DBRefs.  If you prefer not to use DBRefs then you tell GORM to use direct links by using the reference:false mapping.

[Gorm Mapping](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/3.%20Mapping%20Domain%20Classes%20to%20Mongo%20Collections.html)
[Searchable Reference](https://grails.org/wiki/Searchable%20Plugin%20-%20Mapping%20-%20Searchable%20Reference)

Comment: The link that you gave is about `Searchable` which I did not mention.

Comment: I updated the answer to show a link to more relevant content. The Searchable reference uses the reference:true mapping the same as Gorm Mapping.  I thought that the concept could be derived from that searchable link, regardless the answer is the same.